# Does a value type returned from a function trigger a copy-on-write when modified?

Tags: swift, value-type, copy-on-write

Simple question, but I'm not sure how to test.  Does a value type returned from a function always trigger a copy-on-write when it's modified, or are you modifying the exact same instance that was created inside?

For instance, I know this does *not* trigger a copy-on-write since you are modifying the object right when you create it.

```
struct Foo{
    var value:String = "Initial"
}

var a = Foo()
a.value = "Changed" // <- This does *not* make a copy of Foo
```

However, here I'm not sure if the original value is thus orphaned

```
func fooFactory() -> Foo {
    return Foo()
}

var b = fooFactory()
b.value = "Changed again" // <- Does this trigger a copy-on-write in the compiler?
```

The reason for this question is we have some *very heavy* structs that for reasons I can't get into here can't be classes, and our factory methods for those structs are doing a lot of the initial configuration, then the consumers are doing final configuration to them after they are returned from the factory.

I'm trying to see if we're actually creating tons of copies that we're essentially instantly discarding the moment they leave the factory.

### Update:

Here's a test I made that appears to show that yes, a copy is made on the way out even before you've modified it (test 'c' below). Modifying that returned value (test 'd') however doesn't create an additional copy as the copy has already been made upon returning from the function.

That said, I'm not 100% sure this is a valid/accurate test so any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

```
struct Foo {
    var value:Int = 0
}

var lastCheckedPointer:UnsafePointer<Foo>?

func printAddress(_ test: CustomStringConvertible, _ pointer:UnsafePointer<Foo>){

    let observation = lastCheckedPointer.map{
        $0 == pointer
            ? "Same instance"
            : "Copy created"
    } ?? "Initial instance"

    print("Test \(test): \(pointer) - \(observation)")

    lastCheckedPointer = pointer
}

func makeFoo() -> Foo {

    var insideFoo = Foo()
    printAddress("a", &insideFoo)

    insideFoo.value = 1
    printAddress("b", &insideFoo)

    return insideFoo
}

var foo = makeFoo()
printAddress("c", &foo)

foo.value = 2
printAddress("d", &foo)

foo.value = 3
printAddress("e", &foo)

var foo2 = foo
foo2.value = 4
printAddress("f", &foo2)
```

Results:

```
Test a: 0x00007ffc735598d8 - Initial instance
Test b: 0x00007ffc735598d8 - Same instance
Test c: 0x000055cbfb6da1f0 - Copy created <-- This is the returned value
Test d: 0x000055cbfb6da1f0 - Same instance
Test e: 0x000055cbfb6da1f0 - Same instance
Test f: 0x000055cbfb6da1f8 - Copy created
```

Comment: By "some very heavy structs" do you mean they have a lot of properties, or do you mean they have a small number of properties that are very large Arrays/Data/Strings? Copy-on-write isn't a built-in feature of value types in Swift. It's something that specific value types (particularly stdlib collections) manually implement using an internal class buffer and `isKnownUniquelyReferenced`. If you have a struct with many properties, they're going to get copied no matter what unless you implement copy-on-write yourself.

Comment: There currently is no way to *know* that a copy-on-write will be avoided in non-trivial cases (and even some pretty trivial cases aren't promised). It's subject to the optimizer. There is work going on to improve this in future versions of Swift: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md

Comment: Following on from what Rob said above, if you need to implement copy-on-write for your own structs Mike Ash wrote a blog post a while back that shows how to do it https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-04-17-lets-build-swiftarray.html. Although this shows how to implement Array, the technique can be applied to any value type.

Comment: In no particular order, giant structs with 50-80 properties, some with nested arrays of further objects, defined externally to our company so we can't change them. Everything's working at present, but we've seen cases where switching from a struct to a class drastically reduced compile size due to removing the copy-on-write generated code.  Then that kicked off a thought-process which led me to this question.  So it's more from trying to understand the internals more.  I think my test case above proves it *is* the same instance, meaning there would be no reason to change that approach.

Comment: @RobNapier, does that mean my test above is *not* a valid test for our custom value types because `Array<Int>` may be doing something special whereas ours will  get copied 'no matter what'?  I tried to figure out how to get the address for *any* value type but ran into a wall, but `Array` already had `withUnsafeBytes` so I built the test around that type instead.

Comment: Correct. This is not a valid test. Array has an internal ArrayBuffer class that it uses to reduce copying of the contents. Structs themselves are *always* copied when they are passed (it's just that the large storage happens to be implemented by a pointer to a reference type. The pointer itself is copied). CoW is not actually a language feature.

Comment: @RobNapier, just added a new test.  LMK if that's better.  This does seem to confirm that yes, a copy is made on the way out.

Comment: Your test is showing you the worst case, but it's not showing you the best case. The use of `&` here is actually forcing a copy in some cases where it wouldn't otherwise be needed. For example, try replacing the calls to `printAddress` with `withUnsafePointer(to: insideFoo) { print($0) }` and you'll see no copies are made. In fact, since Foo is just an Int, it wouldn't necessarily require storage *at all* if it weren't for the requirement to print an address (Swift is allowed to optimize it into a register, though looking at the assembly I don't think it does).

Comment: The trouble is that Swift doesn't make any promises, so you have to assume the worst case. It makes certain kinds of low-level programming very frustrating. (This was written before the availability of `Data` in Swift, but it addresses some of the issues you're seeing: https://robnapier.net/nsdata)

Comment: Yeah, good info about the small size and registers. I was more trying to find out if it was *guaranteed* to return the inner instance and set it to the var at the return, but I'm thinking that guarantee can't be made. But I will update it with your suggested code above.  Again, the point is I'm trying to find out if some of our functions are (possibly) making copies when we weren't expecting them to.  Honestly, it's more for a deeper understanding of what Swift is doing more so than any optimizations.